# Blazor Get Null Value Exception

Tags: null, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I already get the data from webapi. But it still show null value exception. it should be getting the data before rendering. also there is statement to check null already. it passed but still error

I already get the data from webapi. But it still show null value exception. it should be getting the data before rendering. also there is statement to check null already. it passed but still error

Razor component code

```
    @page "/rolepermission/{roleId}"
@inject HttpClient client
@inject IJSRuntime js

<h3>Roles</h3>
<small>Add as many role as you wish.</small>
<br />
<div class="card">
    <div id="viewAll" class="card-body table-responsive">
            <input asp-for="@permissionDto.RoleId" type="hidden" />
            <table class="table table-striped" id="permissionTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Type
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Permission
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Status
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @if (permissionDto != null)
                    {
                        @foreach (RoleClaimsDto roleClaimsDto in permissionDto.RoleClaims)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input @bind="roleClaimsDto.Type" type="hidden" />
                                    @roleClaimsDto.Type
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input @bind="@roleClaimsDto.Value" type="hidden" />
                                    @roleClaimsDto.Value
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="form-check m-1">
                                        <input @bind="roleClaimsDto.Selected" class="form-check-input" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }

                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding: 20px 20px 0px 0px">
                <button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-success">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>



@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string roleId { get; set; }

    PermissionDto permissionDto = new PermissionDto();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        permissionDto = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<PermissionDto>("api/permission/allPermission/" + roleId);
    }

    async Task AddNewRole()
    {
        //    await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/roles", roleRequest);
        await OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

This is my  produced exception when accessing the route url.

```
    blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at PermissionBlazorApp.Client.Pages.User.RolePermissions.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder) in C:\Users\Chhin Sras\source\repos\PermissionBlazorApp\PermissionBlazorApp\Client\Pages\User\RolePermissions.razor:line 28
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<.ctor>b__6_0(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
```

Comment: It seems your `RoleClaims` is `null`. As you cannot perform iterations on `null` thus you're seeing `object reference error`. Why not place a breakpoint and see if `permissionDto.RoleClaims` has any values to iterate over?

Comment: I dont get it why. but I just add this check line  @if (permissionDto.RoleClaims != null) then it works

Answer (score 1):

Probably your `roleClaimsDto` is null, so accessing it like `roleClaimsDto.Type` causes the null reference exceptions.

If you expect that there could be null objects in your enumerable, you could iterate through it using

`@foreach (RoleClaimsDto roleClaimsDto in permissionDto.RoleClaims.Where(x => x != null))`

Comment: I dont get it why. but I just add this check line @if (permissionDto.RoleClaims != null) then it works

Comment: yes, adding `@if (permissionDto.RoleClaims != null)` as you mentioned  does the same filtering of null items as I suggested. Though then you get an extra nested if statement. Alternatively you can also do `@if (permissionDto.RoleClaims == null) { continue } `